# VBA - Getting Runtime Error 91 "Object Variable or With block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am running a simple macro to paste contents from Excel range into a Word doc. It worked perfectly before but now I am getting

> Runtime Error 91
> Object variable or with block variable not set

The code is below.

Any ideas how to get this to run?

```vb
Sub CopyALLtoWord()
    Dim objWord, objDoc As Object
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet1").Cells(3, 3)
        Worksheets("worksheet1").Range("n5").Value = i

        Range("N5").Select
        Calculate

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet1").Range("L12:AK85").Select
        Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

        'Select Word & paste
        Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        objWord.Selection.Paste
    
        objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

I tried to debug and it highlighted the line `objWord.Selection.Paste`.

Comment: There's no active selection in Word?  Is there a document open?

Comment: The code is supposed to paste range from "Worksheet1" into an empty Word Doc. I have Word open in another window. It has worked before and now has suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Word is open, but is there a document open in Word?

Comment: Yes there is a blank document open in word

Comment: Check Task Explorer to make sure you only have one instance of Word running.  You may have other (possibly hidden instances) open, and GetObject may have attached to one of those.  Maybe add `objWord.Visible = True` right after the GetObject line, to make sure you're not using a hidden instance.

Comment: objWord is being initiated as a variable, not an object. I'm not sure if this is a possible cause for your issue but it is good practice to declare variables properly `Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object`

Answer (score -1):

Try your code with a newly opened blank document. In this case it will be the active document. I tested it with this snippet, and works.

```
Sub objword()
Dim obj As Word.Application

Set obj = GetObject(, "word.application")
Range("A1:A10").Copy
obj.Selection.Paste
Debug.Print "345"
End Sub
```

SIDENOTE: At the end the Debug.Print is for testing purposes, because when i step through the code with F8, after executing the Paste it finishes the program like hit F5. (I don't know why)